Setting CURLOPT_TIMEOUT does not have any effect in pgsql-http
I'm trying to get encounter records from happywhale and save them in my local db with this code shown below:
do
$$
declare
    fromTime timestamp := '2000-01-01'::timestamp;
    toTime timestamp := 'now'::timestamp;
    deltaTime interval := '1 day'::interval;
    
    currTime timestamp;
    response record;
begin
    perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', '30');
    perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE', '30');
    create table if not exists encounters(id integer primary key, region text, species text, startdate timestamp, mincount integer, maxcount integer, geom geometry(point, 4326));
    currTime := fromTime;
    while currTime <= toTime loop
         select * into response from http((
              'POST'
             ,'https://critterspot.happywhale.com/v1/cs/admin/encounter/search'
             ,array[http_header('Connection', 'keep-alive'), http_header('Host', 'critterspot.happywhale.com')]
             ,'application/json'
             ,jsonb_build_object('showConnections', false, 'encounter', jsonb_build_object('datesearch', jsonb_build_object('startdate', to_char(currTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'type', 0)))
         )::http_request);
         if response.status <> 200 then
             raise notice '[%] %', currTime, (response.content::json)->>'message';
         else
             insert into encounters select
                  (e->>'id')::int
                 ,e->>'region'
                 ,e->>'species'
                 ,((e#>>'{dateRange,startDate}')::date + (e#>>'{dateRange,startTime}')::time)
                 ,(e->>'minCount')::int minCount
                 ,(e->>'maxCount')::int maxCount
                 ,ST_Point((e#>>'{location,lng}')::float, (e#>>'{location,lat}')::float, 4326) geom
             from (select json_array_elements(response.content::json) e) on conflict (id) do nothing;
             
             raise notice '[%] %', currTime, response.status;
             currTime := currTime + deltaTime;
         end if;
    end loop;
end;
$$

However, sending requests in a loop always raises a timeout error and cannot be solved by changing CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
NOTICE:  [2000-01-01 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-02 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-03 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-04 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-05 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-06 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-07 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-08 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-09 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-10 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-11 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-12 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-13 00:00:00] 200
NOTICE:  [2000-01-14 00:00:00] 200
ERROR:  Failed to connect to critterspot.happywhale.com port 443 after 1001 ms: Timeout was reached
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select *               from http((
              'POST'
             ,'https://critterspot.happywhale.com/v1/cs/admin/encounter/search'
             ,array[http_header('Connection', 'keep-alive'), http_header('Host', 'critterspot.happywhale.com')]
             ,'application/json'
             ,jsonb_build_object('showConnections', false, 'encounter', jsonb_build_object('datesearch', jsonb_build_object('startdate', to_char(currTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'type', 0)))
         )::http_request)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 15 at SQL statement 

I tried to set curl options CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE using
perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', '30');
perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE', '30');


I believe I solved this issue by setting these options
perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', '10000');
perform http_set_curlopt('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', '10000');

